# section(overflow:scroll) hides my text next to it

Tags: html, css

I've created a section and added overflow:scroll aswell as a postion:absolute so that my text that I've put in my lines dont get under but next to my section.

But now i do not know what to do since my text is inside my section,I've been douing a old html page when css wasn't introduced yet, i saw that my text had a width and height position but i would like to not change it and only apply a way to separate them

```css
body {
  background-color: rgba(170, 200, 228, 0.3);
}

section {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  max-width: 400px;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
  position: absolute;
}

.center {
  vertical-align: top;
  position: absolute;
}

header {
  border: 10px ridge #1173A4;
}

.menu {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #3CA9DF;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.menu a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.information {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.information .informationbtn {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
}

.information .informationbtn a {
  padding: 0px 0px;
}

.menu a:hover,
.information:hover .informationbtn {
  background-color: #7FB8D5;
}

.information-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #7FB8D5;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.information-content a {
  float: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.information-content a:hover {
  background-color: #333;
}

.information:hover .information-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="collegecss.css" />
  <title>college sainte marie </title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <a href="../premierepage.html"><img src="../saintemarie.png"></a>
    <h1>
      <titre>Bienvenue dans le site du Lycée Sainte-Marie</titre>
      <h1>
  </header>

  <div class="menu">
    <a href="#">accueil</a>

    <div class="information">
      <button class="informationbtn"><a href="../premierepage.html"> information générale</a></button>
      <div class="information-content">
        <a href="#">inscription</a>
        <a href="#">historique</a>
        <a href="#">accéder au collège</a>
        <a href="#">horaires</a>
        <a href="#">règlement</a>
        <a href="#">tarifs</a>
      </div>

    </div>
    <a href="#">calendrier</a>
    <a href="#">visite</a>
    <a href="#">pastorale</a>
    <a href="#">vie du collège</a>
  </div>

  <section>
    qdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsf<br /> qdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsfqdfqfsqfsqfqsfqsfqsfqsfqsf
    <br />

  </section>


  <div align="center">
    <center>
      <font size="5" color="#000080">
        INFORMATIONS GENERALES&nbsp; <br>
      </font>
      <font size="2" color="#000080">
        <br>
      </font>
      </b><img border="0" src="images/barre.gif" width="600" height="5"></p>

      <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse; " id="AutoNumber1" width="900" height="167" border="0">
        <tr>
          <td width="877" height="1" align="center" style="padding:0; " colspan="3"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="1425" height="1" align="center" style="border-style: none; border-width: medium" valign="middle" colspan="5">
            <b><font size="4">Le collège Sainte Marie c'est :<br>
&nbsp;</font></b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="400" height="221" align="left" style="border-style: none; border-width: medium" valign="top">
            <p align="center"><b><font color="#800000">un accompagnement scolaire <br>
    au cœur d'un 
    collège ouvert à tous : </font></b></p>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <p style="line-height: 150%">Soutien, approfondissement</li>

              <li>
                <p style="line-height: 150%">Etudes du soir</li>





          </td>
          <td width="40" height="221" align="left" style="border-style: none; border-width: medium" valign="top">
            &nbsp;</td>
          <td width="487" height="221" align="left" style="border-style: none; border-width: medium" valign="top">
            <p align="center">
              <b>
    <font color="#800000">un accompagnement artistique, culturel et sportif dans un 
    cadre de verdure agréable en plein centre ville, bien équipé :</font></b></p>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <p style="line-height: 150%">Activités périscolaires (chorale, atelier artistique)</li>
            </ul>
            <p style="line-height: 150%" align="center">
              </font>
              </i>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <p style="line-height: 150%">Association sportive</li>
                <p style="line-height: 150%" align="center">

                  <li>
                    <p style="line-height: 150%">Voyages scolaires (Espagne, Angleterre...)</li>
              </ul>
          </td>
          <td width="42" height="221" align="left" style="border-style: none; border-width: medium" valign="top">
            &nbsp;</td>
          <td width="404" height="221" align="left" style="border-style: none; border-width: medium" valign="top">
            <p style="line-height: 150%" align="center"><b><font color="#800000">une petite structure qui permet :</font></b></p>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <p style="line-height: 150%">une meilleure connaissance de chacun,</li>
              <li>
                <p style="line-height: 150%">un meilleur suivi</li>
              <li>
                <p style="line-height: 150%">une disponibilité auprès de l'élève et de sa famille
              </li>
              <li>
                <p style="line-height: 150%">un espace d'animation d'écoute et de partage (actions de solidarité, initiation culture et religions, rencontre de témoins ...</li>
            </ul>
            <p style="line-height: 150%">&nbsp;
              <p style="line-height: 150%" align="center">


        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="1425" height="57" align="center" style="border-style: none; border-width: medium" valign="middle" colspan="5">
            <b><font size="4">Découvrez notre collège en détail :</font></b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="266" height="128" align="center" style="border-style: none; border-width: medium" valign="middle">
            <img border="0" src="images/bouton.bmp" width="80" height="30">
            <p>
              <font color="#0000FF" size="4">
                <a target="principal" title="Comment s'inscrire ?" href="inscriptions.htm">Inscriptions</a></font>
          </td>
          <td width="43" height="128" align="center" style="border-style: none; border-width: medium" valign="middle">
            &nbsp;</td>
          <td width="505" height="128" align="center" style="border-style: none; border-width: medium" valign="middle">
            <img border="0" src="images/bouton.bmp" width="80" height="30">
            <p>
              <font color="#800000" size="4">
                <a title="Histoire du collège" target="principal" href="historique.htm">Historique</a></font>
          </td>
          <td width="38" height="128" align="center" style="border-style: none; border-width: medium" valign="middle">
            &nbsp;</td>
          <td width="573" height="128" align="center" style="border-style: none; border-width: medium" valign="middle">
            <img border="0" src="images/bouton.bmp" width="80" height="30">
            <p>
              <font color="#000080" size="4">
                <a target="principal" title="Situation du collège" href="accederaucollege.htm">Accéder
    au collège</a></font>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="266" height="101" align="center" style="border-style: none; border-width: medium" valign="middle">
            <img border="0" src="images/bouton.bmp" width="80" height="30">
            <p>
              <font color="#000080" size="4">
                <a target="principal" title="Horaires" href="horaires.htm">Horaires</a></font>
          </td>
          <td width="43" height="101" align="center" style="border-style: none; border-width: medium" valign="middle">&nbsp;</td>
          <td width="505" height="101" align="center" style="border-style: none; border-width: medium" valign="middle"><img border="0" src="images/bouton.bmp" width="80" height="30">
            <p>
              <font color="#000080" size="4" face="Arial">
                <a target="principal" title="Règlement" href="reglement.htm">Règlement</a></font>
          </td>
          <td width="38" height="101" align="center" style="border-style: none; border-width: medium" valign="middle">
            &nbsp;</td>
          <td width="573" height="101" align="center" style="border-style: none; border-width: medium" valign="middle">
            <img border="0" src="images/bouton.bmp" width="80" height="30">
            <p>
              <font color="#000080" size="4">
                <a target="principal" title="Tarifs" href="tarifs.htm">Tarifs</a></font>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </center>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

i need to add that i wrote this page in french , so if you need traduction can you ask mee in the comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to put the content in a div and set its width/height.
also try adding some padding to it.

and change the overflow to auto.

```
overflow:auto
```